# Decoding/Debugging stripe.js: The value of the property 'Stripe' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, wxpython, stripe-payments, wxwidgets

I'm following the stripe server integration guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#integrate). My server creates a stripe session, and returns:

```
<HTML lang=en><HEAD><TITLE>Payments</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Loading.....</H1>
loading stripe
<SCRIPT src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></SCRIPT>
done loading stripe
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
try {
    document.writeln('creating Stripe object');
    // error occurs here, Stripe is undefined
    var stripe = Stripe('<PUBLIC KEY GOES HERE>');
    document.writeln('redirecting to checkout');
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: '<SESSION ID GOES HERE>'
    }).then(function (result) {
    });
    document.writeln('done calling javascript');
}
catch(error) {
    document.writeln('error occurred: ' + error.message);
}
</SCRIPT>
<H1>....DONE</H1></BODY></HTML>
```

***NOTE: the public key and session id have been redacted***

This works fine when loaded by firefox/ie explorer, but when using [wxWidgets Webview](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.html2.WebView.html) which uses ie explorer as it's backend it throws

> The value of the property 'Stripe' is null or undefined, not a
>   Function object

wxpython webview code:

```
import wx, traceback
from wx.html2 import WebView, EVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR, EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW, \
    WEBVIEWIE_EMU_IE11

html = """<HTML lang=en><HEAD><TITLE>Payments</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Loading.....</H1>
loading stripe
<SCRIPT src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></SCRIPT>
done loading stripe
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
try {
    document.writeln('creating Stripe object');
    // error occurs here, Stripe is undefined
    var stripe = Stripe('<PUBLIC KEY GOES HERE>');
    document.writeln('redirecting to checkout');
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: '<SESSION ID GOES HERE>'
    }).then(function (result) {
    });
    document.writeln('done calling javascript');
}
catch(error) {
    document.writeln('error occurred: ' + error.message);
}
</SCRIPT>
<H1>....DONE</H1></BODY></HTML>  """


class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, size=(1000, 800))
        self._times_loaded = 0
        self.webview = WebView.New(self)  # type: WebView
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR, self.on_error)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED, self.on_loaded)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING, self.on_navigate)
        self.webview.Bind(EVT_WEBVIEW_NEWWINDOW, self.on_new_window)
        # wx.CallAfter(self.load_gateway)
        wx.CallAfter(self.load_html)

        self.Show()

    # def load_gateway(self, evt=None):
    #     self.webview.LoadURL(url)

    def load_html(self):
        self.webview.SetPage(html, "www.stripe.com")

    def reset_page(self):
        self.webview.SetPage(self.webview.GetPageSource(), url)

    # def redirect_to_checkout(self):
    #     # stripe.
    #     session= stripe.checkout.session.Session.create(test_stripe_public_key)

    def on_error(self, evt):
        print(f"error occurred: {evt}")

    def on_navigate(self, evt):
        print("on navigate")

    def on_loaded(self, evt):
        print("loaded")
        self._times_loaded += 1

    def on_new_window(self, evt):
        print("new window event")


try:
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
except:
    input(traceback.format_exc())
```

For some reason the first script at https://js.stripe.com/v3/ doesn't create the `Stripe` object when called with the ie explorer emulator. 
I assumed it was an issue with an unsupported user-agent so I replaced all user-Agent references in the [stripe script](https://js.stripe.com/v3/) with

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

which didn't work. I tried to read through https://js.stripe.com/v3/ to see why Stripe would be undefined. My javascript skills are pretty weak and it is clearly minified/obfuscated so I'm having a difficult time understanding how and why `Stripe` would be undefined. It looks like it's declared dynamically, but what about the emulated browser is causing it to be undefined?

**--------------Update 9-23-19---------------**

After @duck suggested it might be a problem with my script running before the stripe script was loaded I changed the html to sequence the redirect function to run after stripe was loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Payments</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectToCheckout(evt){
        try {
            document.writeln('loading stripe.js')
            var stripe = Stripe('REDACTED');
            document.writeln('redirecting to checkout');
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: 'REDACTED'
            }).then(function (result) {
            });
            document.writeln('done calling javascript');
        }
        catch(error) {
            document.writeln('error occurred: ' + error.message);
        }
    }
    //source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file
    function loadScript(url, callback)
        {
            // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
            //document.writeln('loading stripe script');
            console.log('loading stripe script');
            var head = document.head;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = url;

            // Then bind the event to the callback function.
            // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
            script.onreadystatechange = callback;
            script.onload = callback;

            // Fire the loading
            head.appendChild(script);
        }

    function loadStripe(evt){
        loadScript('https://js.stripe.com/v3/', redirectToCheckout);
        }

    var onloadScript = loadStripe; 

    if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', onloadScript);
    } else {
        if(window.onload) {
            var curronload = window.onload;
            var newonload = function(evt) {
                curronload(evt);
                onloadScript(evt);
            };
            window.onload = newonload;
        } else {
            window.onload = onloadScript;
        }
    }

    </script>

Page loaded
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible it has something to do with IE compatibility?

Comment: I'm not sure, it works when I navigate to the url in IE and they're both using the trident engine- I can edit the script before I serve it I just don't know what's causing Stripe to be undefined

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like the stripe.js script has not loaded before executing your javascript. Does it make any difference if you place your Stripe code inside a window: load listener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: @duck I changed the code to run the redirect function after stripe was loaded and got the same result (works on firefox, fails on the emulated browser)

Comment: @user2682863, there is a key in registry for the IE compatibility (unfortunately I don't remember where and what - just google it). I believe it needs to be set to 11 (highest). See if it makes the difference.

Comment: @duck I got it to work by removing the `document.writeln` calls. Apparently that was overwriting the script code if it was called after the document was loaded?? I still don't fully understand js. Thanks to both of you for helping

Comment: Try adding the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />